# Pass parameter from java to js in Tapestry

Tags: java, javascript, tapestry

I use Apache Tapestry as web application framework.

I have variable in my java code. I need value of this variable in javascript after page loaded.

For example java class:

```
@Import(library = "RoomManagement.js")
public final class RoomManagement{
  @Property
  private long contactId;
}
```

and js in RoomManagement.js:

```
window.onload = function(){
    alert(contactId);
}
```

How can I pass it directly to javascript?

I can not pass value to js like to template, cause it is .js file not .tml.

I can add invisible tag to my page, write value to this tag and read it from js.
But do you know another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the [`JavaScriptSupport`](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/tapestry5/services/javascript/JavaScriptSupport.html) service.

Your java file:

```
@Import(library = "RoomManagement.js")
public final class RoomManagement{

  @Inject
  private JavaScriptSupport javascriptSupport;

  @Property
  private long contactId;

  @AfterRender
  private void setup() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("contactId", contactId);
    javascriptSupport.addInitializerCall("RoomManagement",jsonObject);
  }
}
```

Your RoomManagement.js

```
Tapestry.Initializer.RoomManagement = function (parameters) {
    //do whatever you need here
    alert('Your contactId: ' + parameters.contactId);
};
```